# How to get value of first, second and third element from an .each loop in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, each

I have an HTML form with a number of checkboxes that all have the same class=`"myClass"`.

How I can get the first, second and third value out of these? There can only be three checkboxes checked at a time but it can also be only two, one or none.

I tried the following but this doesn't work:

```
var check1 = 'myDefaultValue';
var check2 = 'myDefaultValue';
var check3 = 'myDefaultValue';
var checkedBoxes = $('.myClass:checked');
    if(checkedBoxes.length == 1) {
        check1 = checkedBoxes[0].val();
    }
    if(checkedBoxes.length == 2) {
        check2 = checkedBoxes[1].val();
    }
    if(checkedBoxes.length == 3) {
        check3 = checkedBoxes[2].val();
    }
```

Comment: use `$('.myClass:checked').each(function(){ //value will be  this.val(); })` to get the selected values of 3,2 or 1 checkboxes

Comment: Thanks - my problem with this is that there are not always three boxes checked so how would I get the different values ? Just add :first, :second, :third ?

Comment: When you access a jQuery Array using brackets: `checkedBoxes[0]` you are retrieving the DOM element in that position. Hence calling `.val()` on it afterward is not recognized because it is no longer a jQuery Object.

Comment: When are you trying to retrieve the values of the checkboxes? On form submit or whenever someone checks a box?

Comment: This is within a modal so when the modal is closed. I then want to pass these values through an Ajax call to make a db update.

Comment: This would return the values of only those checkboxes which are checked, not the unchecked one

Comment: Thanks - Yes, I only need the checked ones and otherwise want to keep the default value I set before.

Comment: @All: If the above does not work could I use something like the following: $('.myClass:checked:first').val(); $('.myClass:checked:second').val(); $('.myClass:checked:third').val();

Comment: When someone checks a checkbox the value of the checkbox is changed??

Comment: No, but the variables have a default value and only should get overwritten if a checkbox is checked.

Comment: Maybe something like this 
$('.myClass:checked').eq(0).val(); 
$('.myClass:checked').eq(1).val(); 
$('.myClass:checked').eq(2).val();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the 3 first checked input fields you could do it with :eq() in the jquery selector like this:

```
    // Get the first three values of all checked fields
    var first = $('.myClass:checked:eq(0)').val();
    var second = $('.myClass:checked:eq(1)').val();
    var third = $('.myClass:checked:eq(2)').val();
```

see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/y0mwy5v8/

Comment: This is it - thanks a lot ! I will accept as soon as I can. :)